# Why is there an unexpected symbol in my R code?

Tags: r

I am not exactly sure what to change in my r code to remove the unexpected symbol.

```
Error: unexpected symbol in "LP=function(n1,n2,m2){N_hat_LP=(((n1)*(n2))/m2) return(N_hat_LP)}"
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you have the return command on the same line as the defining of `N_hat_LP`.

You could put the `return(N_hat_LP)` command on the next line.

In fact, you can simplify this greatly to just:

```
LP=function(n1,n2,m2){((n1)*(n2))/m2}
```

There's no point in defining `N_hat_LP` just to `return` it. R understands if you simply include what you want to do with the parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You need to format your code. To prevent this, I recomment to read a style guide http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/style.html. To solve the error, you can reformat:

```
LP <- function(n1, n2, m2) {
  N_hat_LP <- n1 * n2 / m2
  return(N_hat_LP)
}
```

Or leaf it in one line:

```
LP=function(n1,n2,m2){N_hat_LP=(((n1)*(n2))/m2);return(N_hat_LP)}
```